# How can I add a logo to a presentation?

Tags: slideshows

I am trying to make a presentation with Mathematica and would like to know if there is a way to add a logo that will show in every slide.

I have not found any settings that would allow me to do that automatically and would like to know if there is a straightforward way of implementing this. I tried using a custom template with the logo but this also seemed impossible since custom templates are not possible, to my knowledge, with Mathematica presentations.

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Unfortunately your question does not appear in a form that would be well appreciated. What have you tried? Where have you got stuck? What are restrictions for appropriate answers? What does "ma" mean?

Comment: I agree with Artes. Try `DockedCells`.

Comment: @Artes perhaps you appreciate more the edited version

Comment: @Kuba thanks for the lead, even though i couldn't work out what i wanted

Comment: @someuser_ Slightly better, but I'm still not quite satisfied. Other M.SE users appreciate when they can learn something from questions, even when they are not asked by leading experts. The better question you ask the more it will be appreciated, I hope this rule is still valid on mathematica.stackexchange.

Comment: this link should help you with making your docked cell: http://ibnhconsulting.blogspot.com.au/2011/09/creating-margin-graphics-custom.html

Comment: @MikeHoneychurch Thanks thats also quite useful

Answer (score 4):

During the [Wolfram Virtual Conference 2012](http://www.wolfram.com/events/virtual-conference/2012/resources.html) there was a talk on ["Presentations with Personality"](http://www.wolfram.com/events/virtual-conference/2012/notebooks/VC2012PresentationsWithPersonality.zip). I think they showed how to personalize the slides.

Comment: Very informative, thanks!